# Passing DropDown selected value along with other selected query result set

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, dom-events

I have a form "test.cfm"  It passes values to an action page "testAction.cfm"!

test.cfm does the following:-

1. A drop down box “fruitsList”.
2. A query “qryFruits” that pulls data and then displays the query-result set
3. “Add” button for every query-result set

How it should work:-

5. The dropdown “fruitsList” is to be selected.
6. Once the “Add” button in the result list is selected the “query-result set -CurrentRow” value is to be passed.

Add button is passing the “query-resultset -CurrentRow”  value but NOT the "Drop down" Value.

How to pass the “dropdown- selected-value”?

```
    <!--- test.cfm --->
    <script type="text/javascript" >
          function assign_fruits()
         //  
         {
           var a = document.fruitsForm.fruitsList.selectedIndex;
           document.getElementById('salesForce').value = document.fruitsForm.fruitsList.options[a].value; 
           }
        </script>
    
    <form name="fruitsForm" >
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <select name="fruitsList" onChange="assign_fruits()">
         <option disabled="true">select One
         <option value="m1">apple
         <option value="m2" selected>orange
         <option value="m3">banana
         <option value="m4">grape
         <option value="m5">mango
        </select> 
       </td>
<!--- Trying to assign the DD-value to an input field --->
 <input  name="salesForce" value=""> 
      </tr> 
     <cfquery name="qryFruits" datasoure="#dsn#">
      Select values from Fruits_Table
     </cfquery>
     <cfloop startrow="1" endrow="#qryFruits.recordcount#" query="qryFruits">
      <cfoutput>
      <tr> 
       <td><a href="testAction.cfm">Add</a></td>     
      </tr>   
      </cfoutput>
     </cfloop>
    </table>
    
    </form>
```

Comment: How are you passing anything?  You don't have an AJAX call, you don't have a form submit or action, and your JS doesn't assign values anywhere.  Where are you trying to ass values to?  To test.cfm via the links you generate?

Comment: How are you passing anything? Via "href" link in "Add" button.

Comment: You don't have an AJAX call,?No,Using cfquery to pull data.

Comment: you don't have a form submit or action? submitting via "href" link in "Add" button.

Comment: and your JS doesn't assign values anywhere?????Corrected the issue. Assigned  values to an form field.

Comment: Where are you trying to ass values, test.cfm via the links you generate?? an action file called "testAction.cfm"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going about this a bit unconventionally but I believe the following does what you're looking for:

```
 <cfdump var="#form#">

<!--- test.cfm --->
<cfset qryFruits = queryNew("fruitID,fruitName")>
<cfset queryAddRow(qryFruits, 2)>
<cfset querySetCell(qryFruits, "fruitID", 1, 1)>
<cfset querySetCell(qryFruits, "fruitName", "Kiwi", 1)>
<cfset querySetCell(qryFruits, "fruitID", 2, 2)>
<cfset querySetCell(qryFruits, "fruitName", "Lime", 2)>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    function assign_fruits() {
        var a = document.fruitsForm.fruitsList.selectedIndex;
        document.getElementById('salesForce').value = document.fruitsForm.fruitsList.options[a].value; 
    }
    function submit(id) {
        document.getElementById('fruitClicked').value = id;
        document.forms["fruitsForm"].submit();
    }
</script>

<form name="fruitsForm" id="fruitsForm" action="index.cfm" method="post">
    <p>
        <select name="fruitsList" onChange="assign_fruits();">
            <option value="">select One</option>
            <option value="m1">apple</option>
            <option value="m2" selected>orange</option>
            <option value="m3">banana</option>
            <option value="m4">grape</option>
            <option value="m5">mango</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <!--- Trying to assign the DD-value to an input field --->
    <p>Fruit Slected from List Above: <input name="salesForce" id="salesForce" value=""></p>
    <p>Fruit Clicked Below: <input name="fruitClicked" id="fruitClicked" value=""></p>
    <cfloop startrow="1" endrow="#qryFruits.recordcount#" query="qryFruits">
    <cfoutput>
        <div></div><a href="##" onclick="submit(#qryFruits.fruitID#);">#qryFruits.fruitName#</a></div>
    </cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</form>
```

**Note that you are missing "id" attributes in some of your elements which was causing your JavaScript to fail.**

Comment: +1 this is more or less how I'd go about answering this question. Good job rewriting the code example and making updates to show how you'd solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what the end result is, but are you just trying to pass whatever is output in the #values# to that javascript function?

You can always pass the value directly.

```
<tr>
     <td>#values#  </td> 
     <td><a href="test.cfm" onClick="assign_fruits(#values#);">Add</a></td>          
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript says 
`var a = document.fruitsForm.fruits.selectedIndex;`
but your form field isn't called 'fruits', it's called fruitsList.  Try

```
document.fruitsForm.fruitsList.selectedIndex;
```

instead.

Comment: I have made the changes suggested

Comment: you've added several answers to this question, combine these into one by editing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your output can be simplified slightly.  But I'm still a little unclear what you're trying to do.  What's the purpose of testAction.cfm?

```
<cfoutput query="qryFruits">
        <tr> 
            <td><a href="testAction.cfm?ID=#qryFruits.CurrentRow#">Add #qryFruits.Values#</a></td>           
        </tr>   
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: The issue I was having was in passing the drop-down value across.I am unable to do so still.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to do.  I assume you want to pass a parameter, salesForce, to testAction.cfm.  And the value of it should be m1, m2, m3, ...

So essentially you need to have your urls be like `testAction.cfm?salesForce=m1`  Is this correct?  If so, get rid of the hidden form field and all that javascript.  Is it the case that the fruitsList dropdown is always numbered m1 - mX in sequence?  (i.e. you don't go m1, m79, m4, m2, m99 etc).

And here's an assumption - does the list of fruits in your dropdown correspond to the fruits query?  i.e. is it the same fruits in the same order?  If so you should just ditch the dropdown and only have the links (or vice versa).

```
<!--- test.cfm --->
<cfquery name="qryFruits" datasoure="#dsn#">
  Select values from Fruits_Table
</cfquery>

<table> 
  <cfoutput query="qryFruits">
    <tr> 
        <td><a href="testAction.cfm?salesForce=m#qryFruits.CurrentRow#">Add #qryFruits.Values#</a></td>           
    </tr>   
  </cfoutput>
</table>
```